# Stacked Bar Chart - How to center values inside/outside the bar?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I modified a code (found here in the forum) to produce a stacked bar chart. Unfortunately I do not understand the whole code…
How can I center the values within the bar chart or right beside the chart? Unfortunately there are values outside the chart (0.430, 0.054, …)!

Furthermore: How can I change the Formate? 0.430 --> 43.00% and so on?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[
backend=biber
]
{biblatex}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\centering
\scriptsize

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
Label,1,2,3
a,0.439,0.130,0.430
b,0.874,0.072,0.054
c,0.757,0.061,0.183
d,0.783,0.139,0.078
e,0.451,0.115,0.434
f,0.398,0.115,0.487
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3}}]{sum}{\data}

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage plot/.style={point meta=explicit,every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize,},
    nodes near coords={
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
      \ifnum\iszero=0
      \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
      \fi},
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100.01,
    visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue},
    },
    percentage series/.style={
    table/x expr=\coordindex,
    table/y expr=(\thisrow{#1}/\thisrow{sum}*100),
    table/meta=#1
    }
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width=0.80\textwidth,
    height=0.33\textheight,
    percentage plot,
    bar width=7ex,
    xticklabels from table={\data}{Label},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={align=center},
    legend style={draw=none, font=\scriptsize},
    legend cell align={left},
    legend pos=outer north east
]

\addplot [fill=black!75] table[percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot [fill=black!25] table[percentage series=2] {\data};
\addplot [fill=black!0]  table[percentage series=3] {\data};

\legend{y, p,n}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[Link to original code.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390136/stacked-chart-percentage)

Comment: Could you please explicitly link to the source of your code? I am also asking for that in order to make sense of `\thisrow{sum}`, in your table there is no explicit sum row. This would most likely allow me to address the second part of your question (which I missed in my answer, sorry) in a not too complicated fashion.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to change the anchor of the `nodes near coords`. (I also changed the text color of the lowest nodes for a better readability.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[
backend=biber
]
{biblatex}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\centering
\scriptsize

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
Label,1,2,3
a,0.439,0.130,0.430
b,0.874,0.072,0.054
c,0.757,0.061,0.183
d,0.783,0.139,0.078
e,0.451,0.115,0.434
f,0.398,0.115,0.487
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3}}]{sum}{\data}

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage plot/.style={point meta=explicit,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize,anchor=north,inner
    ysep=1pt},
    nodes near coords={
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
      \ifnum\iszero=0
      \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
      \fi},
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100.01,
    visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue},
    },
    percentage series/.style={
    table/x expr=\coordindex,
    table/y expr=(\thisrow{#1}/\thisrow{sum}*100),
    table/meta=#1
    }
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width=0.80\textwidth,
    height=0.33\textheight,
    percentage plot,
    bar width=7ex,
    xticklabels from table={\data}{Label},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={align=center},
    legend style={draw=none, font=\scriptsize},
    legend cell align={left},
    legend pos=outer north east
]

\addplot [fill=black!75,text=white] table[percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot [fill=black!25] table[percentage series=2] {\data};
\addplot [fill=black!0]  table[percentage series=3] {\data};

\legend{y, p,n}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]